# Why does isolating tasks in task arenas to NUMA nodes for memory locality slow down my embarassingly parallel TBB application?

Tags: c++, c++11, tbb, numa

I have this self-contained example of a TBB application that I run on a 2-NUMA-node CPU that performs a simple vector addition repeatedly on dynamic arrays. It recreates an issue that I am having with a bit more complicated example. I am trying to divide the computations cleanly between the available NUMA nodes by initializing the data in parallel with 2 `task_arenas` that are linked to separate NUMA nodes through TBB's NUMA API. The subsequent parallel execution should then be conducted so that that memory accesses are performed on data that is local to the cpu that computes its task. A control example uses a simple `parallel_for` with a `static_partitioner` to perform the computation while my intended example invokes per `task_arena` a task which invokes a `parallel_for` to compute the vector addition of the designated region, i.e. the half of the dynamic arena that was initialized before in the corresponding NUMA node. This example  always takes twice as much time to perform the vector addition compared to the control example. It cannot be the overhead of creating the tasks for the `task_arena`s that will invoke the `parallel_for` algorithms, because the performance degradation only occurs when the `tbb::task_arena::constraints` are applied. Could anyone explain to me what happens and why this performance penalty is so harsh. A direction to resources would also be helpful as I am doing this for a university project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include <vector>



int main(){
    
    std::vector<int> numa_indexes = tbb::info::numa_nodes();
    std::vector<tbb::task_arena> arenas(numa_indexes.size());
    std::size_t numa_nodes = numa_indexes.size();
    for(unsigned j = 0; j < numa_indexes.size(); j++){
        arenas[j].initialize( tbb::task_arena::constraints(numa_indexes[j]));
    }

    std::size_t size = 10000000;
    std::size_t part_size = std::ceil((float)size/numa_nodes);
    double * A = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    double * B = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    double * C = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    double * D = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*size);


    //DATA INITIALIZATION
    for(unsigned k = 0; k < numa_indexes.size(); k++)
        arenas[k].execute(
        [&](){
            std::size_t local_start = k*part_size;
            std::size_t local_end = std::min(local_start + part_size, size);
            tbb::parallel_for(static_cast<std::size_t>(local_start), local_end,
                [&](std::size_t i)
            { 
                C[i] = D[i] = 0;
                A[i] = B[i] = 1;
            }, tbb::static_partitioner());
        });

    //PARALLEL ALGORITHM
    tbb::tick_count t0 = tbb::tick_count::now();
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        tbb::parallel_for(static_cast<std::size_t>(0), size,
            [&](std::size_t i)
            { 
                C[i] += A[i] + B[i];
            }, tbb::static_partitioner());
    tbb::tick_count t1 = tbb::tick_count::now();
    std::cout << "Time 1: " << (t1-t0).seconds() << std::endl;
        

    //TASK ARENA & PARALLEL ALGORITHM
    t0 = tbb::tick_count::now();
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        for(unsigned k = 0; k < numa_indexes.size(); k++){
        arenas[k].execute(
        [&](){
            for(unsigned i=0; i<numa_indexes.size(); i++)
                task_groups[i].wait();
            task_groups[k].run([&](){
                std::size_t local_start = k*part_size;
                std::size_t local_end = std::min(local_start + part_size, size);
                tbb::parallel_for(static_cast<std::size_t>(local_start), local_end,
                    [&](std::size_t i)
                    { 
                        D[i] += A[i] + B[i];
                    });
            });

        });
    }

    t1 = tbb::tick_count::now();
    std::cout << "Time 2: " << (t1-t0).seconds() << std::endl;

    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        sum1 += C[i];
        sum2 += D[i];
    }

    std::cout << sum1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum2 << std::endl;

    
    return 0;
}
```

Performance with:

```
for(unsigned j = 0; j < numa_indexes.size(); j++){
        arenas[j].initialize( tbb::task_arena::constraints(numa_indexes[j]));
    }
```

```
$ taskset -c 0,1,8,9 ./RUNME
Time 1: 0.896496
Time 2: 1.60392
2e+07
2e+07
```

Performance without constraints:

```
$ taskset -c 0,1,8,9 ./RUNME
Time 1: 0.652501
Time 2: 0.638362
2e+07
2e+07
```

EDIT: I implemented the use of `task_group` as found in  @AlekseiFedotov's suggested resources, but the issue still remains.

Comment: Note: if you are trying to be NUMA aware you should be allocating buffers for each NUMA node *on that node* [Linux provides APIs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/numa) to do so. Otherwise you'll pay the NUMA price with every access to the buffer.

Comment: Extending @Mgetz comment, you may try implementing similar approach for data initialization step. This will make threads migration between arenas less probable.

Comment: I based this approach on the OpenMP guides for NUMA aware programming where statically distributed work on parallel threads on initialization of dynamic arrays and then computation ensures that memory access on computation is mostly limited to local memory. This reliably leads to better performance against data initialization that is performed serially and thus on only one NUMA node and its memory. Are you suggesting that this may not be sufficient and more performance gain may be achievable?

Comment: The OpenMP and the TBB are two different technologies that help solving problems in the same field domain. However, each technology achieves its results using its own approach. Therefore, to squeeze the performance out using a particular technology, the code itself should be organized in way that aligns with the paradigm the used technology implies.

Comment: [Intel Video](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/videos/onetbb-optimizing-for-numa-architectures.html#gs.p653oc) This link for a video on intel regarding NUMA aware tbb programming also shows this approach without the buffering that was mentioned by @Mgetz. The timestamp for it is 20:00.

Comment: @user151387 you don't *have* to do the NUMA aware allocation. But the whole point of doing it is to be aware of the *Non-Uniform Memory Access* and work around it. So it will work of course without it. But if you allocate from the general pool there is no way TBB can easily figure out that slice A of buffer B needs to be copied to node 42 etc. That would require allocation you didn't tell or authorize it to do. What I suggested is an optimization not a requirement. 

Comment: Just curious have you run your code through a profiler? It's highly plausible that something else is causing the slowdown. The first rule of optimization is "profile, then profile again"

Comment: Your suggestions are really valuable and I am grateful for them :). The guides that I mentioned which show a parallel runtime system API inherent strategy for NUMA aware programming  benefitted performance reliably and are easy to implement, which is why I hesitated to implement your suggestions, because it would require additional research and testing until I get it to work. Right now I was able to get it to work with Alekseis answer and compared to other runtimes that I used, the overhead from such explicit task creation on NUMA nodes is more or less similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the provided example where the work with arenas happens is not one-to-one match to [the example from the docs](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneTBB/main/tbb_userguide/Guiding_Task_Scheduler_Execution.html), "Setting the preferred NUMA node" section.

Looking further into [the specification of the `task_arena::execute()` method](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/task_scheduler/task_arena/task_arena_cls.html), we can find out that the `task_arena::execute()` is a blocking API, i.e. it does not return until the passed lambda completes.

On the other hand, [the specification of the `task_group::run()` method](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/task_scheduler/task_group/task_group_cls.html) reveals that its method is asynchronous, i.e. returns immediately, not waiting for the passed functor to complete.

That is where the problem lies, I guess. The code executes two parallel loops within arenas one by one, in a serial manner so to say. Consider following the example from the docs carefully.

BTW, the oneTBB project, which is the revamped version of the TBB, can be found [here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB).

EDIT answer for the EDITED question:

1. See the comment to the question.
2. The waiting should happen after work is submitted, not before it. Also, no need to go to another arena's task group to do the wait *within the loop*, just submit the work in the NUMA loop via `arena[i].execute( [i, &] { task_group[i].run( [i, &] { /*...*/ } ); } )`, then, *in another loop*, wait for each `task_group` within corresponding `task_arena`.

Please note how I capture the NUMA loop iteration by copy. Otherwise, the code might be referring the wrong data inside the lambda body.

Comment: I added the `task_group` as laid out in the documentation and edited the code in my question accordingly but the issue still remains. The tbb version I use is 2021.5 from Intel oneapi.

Comment: I replaced the loop that invokes wait() on all task_groups with just one that is  related to the same computing NUMA node and it solved the issue. But my actual computation is not embarassingly parallel and relies on neighboring values for the computation of each point and requires the synchronization of all task_groups at the end of every iteration. Is this suggested pattern not a viable solution for my issue?